# Extract Text between two strings (Command Line)

Tags: json, command-line, grep, extract, spotify

I'm trying to extract song names from a json file from the Spotify API. The word "name" occurs for both artists and songs, and I'm trying to extract song names.

I tried using grep, but I'm not sure how to look for patterns of strings before and after the desired text (the song name). In this case, the song name is after "name", but before "popularity". In the case of artists' names, the name is after "name" and before "type".

How would I extract the text between the two words?

```
{
  "tracks" : [ {
    "album" : {
      "album_type" : "album",
      "artists" : [ {
        "external_urls" : {
          "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/13ubrt8QOOCPljQ2FL1Kca"
        },
        "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/13ubrt8QOOCPljQ2FL1Kca",
        "id" : "13ubrt8QOOCPljQ2FL1Kca",
        "name" : "A$AP Rocky",
        "type" : "artist",
        "uri" : "spotify:artist:13ubrt8QOOCPljQ2FL1Kca"
      } ],
      "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "ID", "IE", "IS", "IT", "JP", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "SE", "SG", "SK", "SV", "TH", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY" ],
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/1E1eyI5uGllppJZCxNoF9w"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1E1eyI5uGllppJZCxNoF9w",
      "id" : "1E1eyI5uGllppJZCxNoF9w",
      "images" : [ {
        "height" : 640,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/b0dad68115b71ec6c81240eac982da7d14676e6d",
        "width" : 640
      }, {
        "height" : 300,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/342fd8bf9219b2369394bc6adf57a69b3fecc0f7",
        "width" : 300
      }, {
        "height" : 64,
        "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/79d71b48c2fd180c7506a2db2e13ed0a7c8107a2",
        "width" : 64
      } ],
      "name" : "LONG.LIVE.A$AP (Deluxe Version)",
      "type" : "album",
      "uri" : "spotify:album:1E1eyI5uGllppJZCxNoF9w"
    },
    "artists" : [ {
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/13ubrt8QOOCPljQ2FL1Kca"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/13ubrt8QOOCPljQ2FL1Kca",
      "id" : "13ubrt8QOOCPljQ2FL1Kca",
      "name" : "A$AP Rocky",
      "type" : "artist",
      "uri" : "spotify:artist:13ubrt8QOOCPljQ2FL1Kca"
    }, {
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4",
      "id" : "3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4",
      "name" : "Drake",
      "type" : "artist",
      "uri" : "spotify:artist:3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4"
    }, {
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/17lzZA2AlOHwCwFALHttmp"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/17lzZA2AlOHwCwFALHttmp",
      "id" : "17lzZA2AlOHwCwFALHttmp",
      "name" : "2 Chainz",
      "type" : "artist",
      "uri" : "spotify:artist:17lzZA2AlOHwCwFALHttmp"
    }, {
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/2YZyLoL8N0Wb9xBt1NhZWg"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/2YZyLoL8N0Wb9xBt1NhZWg",
      "id" : "2YZyLoL8N0Wb9xBt1NhZWg",
      "name" : "Kendrick Lamar",
      "type" : "artist",
      "uri" : "spotify:artist:2YZyLoL8N0Wb9xBt1NhZWg"
    } ],
    "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "ID", "IE", "IS", "IT", "JP", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "SE", "SG", "SK", "SV", "TH", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY" ],
    "disc_number" : 1,
    "duration_ms" : 233786,
    "explicit" : true,
    "external_ids" : {
      "isrc" : "USRC11201220"
    },
    "external_urls" : {
      "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/track/4XoP1AkbOurU9CeZ2rMEz2"
    },
    "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/4XoP1AkbOurU9CeZ2rMEz2",
    "id" : "4XoP1AkbOurU9CeZ2rMEz2",
    "name" : "F**kin' Problems",
    "popularity" : 80,
    "preview_url" : "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/1649b7c26c8bcfa8b252601cf428844cec9a8446?cid=8897482848704f2a8f8d7c79726a70d4",
    "track_number" : 7,
    "type" : "track",
    "uri" : "spotify:track:4XoP1AkbOurU9CeZ2rMEz2"
  }, {
```

Comment: On which OS ??.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess with a little research you can find lots of solutions to your problem.
For instance if you always have the type of structure you quoted

```
grep name filename  | cut -c15- | rev | cut -c 3- | rev
```

would work. You can probably find more neat and robust solutions but in your case this works.

**EDIT**

Given you new file you can use

```
grep name filename | rev | cut -c 3- | cut -f1 -d'"' | rev
```

Comment: I've edited the code block, although it is very long. The pattern tends to be that for every "name" string that occurs, the artist, album, or song name occurs. After trying the grep you recommended, all three types of names show up. The main way I've found that the song name is different is that it is followed by "popularity".

Comment: I've edited the answer according to your new file. Give it a try. Also when you add code in the question always copy your code, select and click the curly brackets to edit properly. (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

Try with **pcregrep**

```
pcregrep -o1 -M 'name" : "(.*)".*\n.*"popularity'
```